# A way to get an array or hash of all possible associations for a particular class or instance of that class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I'm doing some testing, where it could be really nice, if I could ask a class what associations it has. Just like this example:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Relationships
  has_many    :sellers
  has_many    :adverts
  has_many    :images
end
```

And then do something like...

```
Car.associations #=> [:sellers, :adverts, :images]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `reflect_on_all_associations`.

Comment: Faaaantastic! That was a tricky one :-) Thanks mate http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html#method-i-reflect_on_all_associations